# Which option is the correct one?

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

> Let $\mathbb Q , \mathbb R , \mathbb {R - Q}$ be respectively denote the set of all rational numbers, real numbers and irrational numbers. Suppose $p \in \mathbb {R-Q}$ and $\mathbb Q + p = \{x+p : x\in \mathbb Q \}$. Then which of the following is true?
>
> $(a)$ $\mathbb Q \cup (\mathbb Q + p) =\mathbb R.$
>
> $(b)$ $\mathbb Q + p = \mathbb {R-Q}$ if $p$ is transcendental$.$
>
> $(c)$ $\mathbb Q + p = \mathbb {R-Q}$ if $p$ is algebraic$.$
>
> $(d)$ $\mathbb Q + p$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb {R-Q}.$

My intuition says $(d)$ is the correct option though I may be wrong. But I can't figure out why is it correct if it really so. Would anyone please give me some hint to proceed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $p$ is irrational, then what sort of number is $2p$?

Comment: It is obviously irrational.

Comment: Right, so $2p\notin\Bbb Q$. What else can you say about $2p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}+p$ are countable, this immediately kills the first three options.

Comment: oh thanks @pisco125 I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,(d) is correct since Q+p is a countable set and the Irrationals are uncountable ,